# Как подсветить контуры самого объекта, вместо выделения его в прямоугольник?

Tags: python, opencv, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

```
import os
import cv2
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection, VideoObjectDetection
import pandas as pd

execution_path = os.getcwd()

yolo_model_fn = r'C:\work\ML\.data\misc\yolo.h5'
video_fn = r'C:\download\cut2.mp4'

detector = VideoObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(yolo_model_fn)
detector.loadModel()

data = []

def collect_detected_objs(*args):
    data.append(args)
    #detected.append(pd.DataFrame(detections).assign(frame=frame_pos))
    #stats.append(pd.Series(obj_stats, index=[frame_pos]))

ret = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(
    input_file_path = video_fn,
    output_file_path = os.path.join(execution_path, "traffic_detected"),
    frames_per_second = 20,
    log_progress = True,
    per_frame_function=collect_detected_objs
)

d = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x[1]).assign(frame=x[0]) for x in data])
stats = pd.DataFrame([x[2] for x in data], index=[x[0] for x in data])

print(d)
print(stats)
```

Как подсветить контуры самого объекта, вместо выделения его в прямоугольник?

Comment: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/07/top-10-pretrained-models-get-started-deep-learning-part-1-computer-vision/

Comment: А такой впрос, как найти площадь объекта ( выделенной зоны, допустим контуры человека выделили и надо найти его площадь)?